# How do I insert data into solr through my application which is in c++

Tags: c++, elasticsearch, solr

I want to insert data into solr through my application, I am also using elasticsearch to store data, to insert data in to elasticsearch I am using following request incloding my data in index "16-03-2016-sslindex" :

```
"POST http://192.168.0.164:9200/_bulk HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.164:9200
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0;)
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 196"

"{"index":{"_index": "16-03-2016-sslindex","_type":"session"}}
{"UniqueID":"2016-3-16-10-45-19-1-1","Time":"2016-3-16T10:45:19","SrcIp":"192.168.0.180","SrcPort":1123,"DstIp":"74.125.68.113","DstPort":443,"InterfaceID":"1","LocationID":2,"Size":0,"Snortname":"p_snort.log.123","Dummy1":"","Dummy2":0}"
```

I want to use solr in same ways. what should be the request structure so as to insert valye in to solr.

Comment: which programming language you are using in application ?

Comment: my application is in c++ but for requesting elasticsearch i am using socket programming

Answer (score 0):

Solr support HTTP protocol for insertion/updation/search.....
You have to hit Solr (again by socket programming.)

### In Java

```
public void pumpData() {
// hit elastic cloud
// then hit solr
}
```

(Just for info : Solrj is a java client to access solr. It make task little easy.)

Same you have to do in C++. C++ has "SolrCpp" solr client -  [Solrcpp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/solrcpp/). 
Apache site is mentioning same - [solr clients](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/IntegratingSolr#C.2B-.2B-)

Comment: Is there any way like  currently I am connecting to elastic search, I am unable to understand your solution